# Is it possible to customize the title popup in <a> tag?

Tags: html, css

Sometimes we can add tips for a href link, like:

`<a href="#" title="This link leads you to Page1">Page1</a>`

When the cursor is on the link, sometimes it will take a quite long time to show up the text. Is it possible to change the time, duration and even animation with pure CSS?

Thanks,

Comment: No. It's not possible with pure css. See [Can I customize the in-browser tool tip bubble?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684905/can-i-customize-the-in-browser-tool-tip-bubble)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In css3 you style your tooltip using :after & adding a class to the element.**

css3

```
.tooltip:hover:after {
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 color:#fff;
 content:attr(rel);
 display:block;
 margin-top:-42px;
 position:absolute;
 white-space:nowrap;
}
```

html

```
<a href="#" rel="This link leads you to Page1" class="tooltip">Page1</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eRQLQ/

**And this is with time & delay**

```
.tooltip:after{
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 color:#fff;
 content:attr(rel);
 display:block;
 margin-top:-42px;
 position:absolute;
 white-space:nowrap;
 opacity:0;
 -webkit-transition:opacity 1s ease 2s;
}
.tooltip:hover:after{
 opacity:1;
 -webkit-transition:opacity 1s ease 300ms;
}
```

if you want more support add also the -moz,-ms and other prefixes.

300ms delay on open/close, duration 1s

http://jsfiddle.net/eRQLQ/1/

2s delay on close, duration 1s

http://jsfiddle.net/eRQLQ/2/

**EDIT**

complex

http://jsfiddle.net/eRQLQ/3/

**EDIT 2**

multiple elements inside a container with images arrtibute values and custom text.less html.

http://jsfiddle.net/eRQLQ/8/

Comment: Interesting! what is the difference between `rel` and `title`?

Comment: in this case rel does not appear on screen like title does.i added a more complex fiddle

Comment: i also suggest to add the class to the parent element and change .tooltip with .tooltop>a . this basically allows you to add to the tooltip to all the a elements inside a specific container.

Comment: So we have to use rel rather than title?

Comment: if you want you can also use the title... i prefer the rel

Comment: you can also use a custom data-* attribute like data-title https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: check out the edit 2 example.

Comment: thanks. Actually I just want to use the default one since I guess this would be helpful for SEO. Do you think so?

Answer (score 0):

**The "title" popup is a feature of the web browser designed for accessibility.  There is no way to change it with CSS as that runs counter to its purpose as an accessibility tool.**   That said, you *can* create your own pure HTML/CSS tooltips that do what you want.

The traditional way of making your own tooltips is with JavaScript.  The Twitter Boostrap framework has [a good example](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips), and the JavaScript library Dynamic Drive has [a whole bunch](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex5/index.html).

Instead of JavaScript, you can use CSS `:hover` styles to make your own tooltips.  The simplest way to do this would be to put a `<span class="tooltip">...</span>` inside each `<a>` tag, and to use CSS to position it and style it as necessary.  A good resource to get you started with the tooltip design is http://csstooltip.com/.

If your users are using modern browsers, you can add animation to your custom tooltips.  You may consider starting from an already-existing library such as [Hint.css](http://kushagragour.in/lab/hint/).

(A final note: if you do any of these things, keep in mind that not using the `title` attribute will negatively impact users who rely on this attribute for accessibility.  This may or may not be a problem for your target users, but it is definitely something to keep in mind.  If you need to maintain some level of accessibility, you may want to consider using adding `role="tooltip"` to your tooltip elements.  See the [ARIA Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles) for more details on accessibility using `role` attributes.)