# Is it possible to make CSS transitions synchronous?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

This code below demonstrates how I'm applying CSS transitions to the height property. My understanding of CSS transitions (which is supported by what I'm seeing) is that they are asynchronous. Can anyone tell me how to make CSS transitioning synchronous? I specifically want to use CSS transitions (i.e. not jQuery animations or some other method).

CSS:

```css
.animated {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px);
    transition: height 1.5s;
    -webkit-transition: height 1.5s;
    -webkit-perspective: 1500;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='someElement' class='animated'></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#someElement").css("height","200px");
//More javascript code I'd like to execute after the css animation has completed
```

Comment: What does “synchronous” mean? You want them to tie up the UI and be completely invisible?

Comment: Are you talking about JavaScript? You want to do something there after the transition completes?

Comment: Do you want to wait before something happens, then make use of the timing feature like .3s, or as you have already used in your example?

Comment: Yes, if I have a line of code after the javascript where the css is applied I would like it to not execute until the animation is complete (see edit).

Comment: Set a variable to the duration of the  CSS animation using JavaScript and set a timeout based on that variable?

Comment: CSS animations fire a number of events you can listen for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there isn't really a way to make it synchronous, but you can wait for the animation to end, effectively simulating a synchronous behaviour

### The solution

```
var crossBrowserEvent = 'webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend';

$("#someElement").css("height","200px");

$("#someElement").one('crossBrowserEvent',function(e) {
    do_some();
    magic();
    here();
    when_the_animation_ends();
});
```

### Some additional comments

Because the css3 animations are not yet fully cross browser, you must listen to more then one event. 
Some problems could arise if some of the browsers implement the new **animationEnd** event and also for example the **webkitAnimationEnd** at the same time. That's why I put the **one** event attacher instead of the **on**.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a code that uses pure js and the webkit prefix to create sequential based class changes.**

In the DEMO i use more than just one animation so the handler function is executed many times. Thats why i check for the propertyName('color' in my case). If the color animation ends the handler function changes the className with `classList.toggle('active');`
Each class has different transition lengths.

```
function handler(e){
 //here is when the transition ends.
 // add your code here or:
 if(e.propertyName=='color'){
  e.target.classList.toggle('active');
 }
}
var div=document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
div.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd',handler,false);
div.classList.toggle('active');
```

**DEMO** (chrome safari android ios)

http://jsfiddle.net/jaqT7/

if you want more support search for the various prefixes.-webkit,-ms,-moz
and also the correct transitionend handler.

**And here is an example using sequential animations using simple delay's**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20778358/2450730